# Can't get errorbar to work with position_dodge with geom_point

Tags: r

I am trying to build a plot with several different data points. The first lot of data I am trying to display are the means with the confidence intervals. The second lot of data will be all the points as a jitter. The issue I am encountering is that I can't get the errorbars to `position_dodge` along with the `geom_point`, it just remains centered.

I've created other plots with no trouble, the only difference I can tell is that I am trying to specify the `geom_point` *shape*, so that I can have a black outline around the point for easier identification.

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    watervol.time,
    mapping = aes(
      x = Date.Order,
      y = water.vol.mean,
      ymin = LCI,
      ymax = UCI
    ), 
    colour = "black", width = 10,
    position = position_dodge()
  ) + 
  geom_point(
    watervol.time,
    mapping = aes(
      x = Date.Order,
      y = water.vol.mean,
      fill = Site, group = Site
    ),
    size = 3.5, shape = 21,
    position = position_dodge(11)
  )
```

Output that I'm getting:

[image: 1]

EDIT: sorry, I couldn't figure out any other way to share the data. Values have been changed due to privacy:
Site    Date.Order  water.vol.mean  LCI UCI
Quartz  28/09/2021  27.52666667 23.86938796 31.18394537
Quartz  29/11/2021  44.23333333 40.57605463 47.89061204
Quartz  18/07/2022  45.23666667 41.57938796 48.89394537
Quartz  27/09/2022  40.46   36.80272129 44.11727871
Hematite    28/09/2021  33.18666667 29.52938796 36.84394537
Hematite    29/11/2021  45.65   41.99272129 49.30727871
Hematite    19/07/2022  45.50333333 41.84605463 49.16061204
Hematite    27/09/2022  42.14   38.48272129 45.79727871
Olivine 28/09/2021  26.21333333 22.55605463 29.87061204
Olivine 29/11/2021  43.84333333 40.18605463 47.50061204
Olivine 18/07/2022  44.58066667 40.92338796 48.23794537
Olivine 27/09/2022  39.778  36.12072129 43.43527871
Plagioclase 28/09/2021  32.81666667 29.15938796 36.47394537
Plagioclase 29/11/2021  46.18166667 42.52438796 49.83894537
Plagioclase 19/07/2022  47.66633333 44.00905463 51.32361204
Plagioclase 27/09/2022  44.89196667 41.23468796 48.54924537

Comment: Can you please share your data? It seems like you have `NULL` in place of whatever it is you are trying to plot. For example if your data is saved as `data`, please run `dput(data)` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: I've changed the values due to privacy, so output may look a little different as well as included the str() for the variables. There shouldn't be any NULL values as all the fields contain values/text.             
 $ Site          : Factor
 $ Date.Order    : Date
 $ water.vol.mean: num
 $ LCI           : num
 $ UCI           : num

Comment: Hi @tea4science, as Shawn wrote above, change the values and then copy the output of the `dput` command

Comment: Try including 11 as a value inside the `position_dodge()` command in the `geom_errorbar` statement as you’ve done in the `geom_point` statement.

Comment: Nope, still nothing - the errorbars remain centred along the same vertical axis

Comment: It seems the formatting of your data in your question is still off. Here is an example of how it should look when you paste it into your question (see top section): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74026071/why-do-ggline-and-geom-line-have-different-outputs

Answer (score 0):

Both geoms need to have the same grouping and dodge width. This is best done when you initialise the plot using `ggplot()`

I can't confirm this without a reproducible example, but my guess is:

```
ggplot(watervol.time, 
       aes(x = Date.Order, 
           y = water.vol.mean,
           ymin = LCI,
           ymax = UCI,
           group = Site)) + 
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 11),
                colour = "black", width = 10) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Site),
             position = position_dodge(width = 11),
             size = 3.5, shape = 21)
```

Comment: This does work, but I've been starting the code with ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y)) as I will be adding data from a second dataframe into this plot. The points I'm trying to plot here are the means, while the second lot I want to add will be a geom_jitter of all the individual data points from a different df. I might have to go down the route of using a function to calculate the means and confidence intervals so that I only have to use the one data frame.

Comment: You can use two dataframes, just start the layer with the data argument: `geom_jitter(data = data2)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to put group into both the geom_errorbar and geom_point:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y)) +
geom_jitter(SWC, mapping = aes(x = Date.Order, y = Water_Vol, colour = Site), 
width = 5) +
geom_errorbar(watervol.time, mapping = aes(Date.Order, y = water.vol.mean, 
ymin = LCI, ymax = UCI, group = Site), width = 10, 
position = position_dodge(10)) +
geom_point(data = watervol.time, mapping = aes(Date.Order, y = water.vol.mean, 
fill = Site, group = Site), shape = 21, size = 3.5, 
position = position_dodge(10)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red')) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'))
```